# Ef Core 2.2 and foreign key on the strongly typed ID property

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

I would like to create `one-to-many` relations between two entities. The assumptions are quite simple, I want to have collections of posts on the `Blog` object, and `Post` with id of the blog.

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; private set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; private set; }
    public Blog(BlogId id) {
        Id = id.Id;
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; private set;}
    public virtual BlogId BlogId { get; private set; }
}

public class BlogId: IComparable<int>
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public BlogId(int id)
    {
       Id = id;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(BlogId id) => id.Id;
    public static implicit operator BlogId(int id) => new BlogId(id);
    public int CompareTo(int other) => Id.CompareTo(other);
}
```

**Configuration:**

```
public class BlogConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Blog>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Blog> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Blogs");
        builder.HasKey("Id");
        builder.HasMany(n => n.Posts)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogId)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}

public class PostConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Post> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Posts");
        builder.HasKey("Id");
        builder.Property(p => p.BlogId)
            .HasConversion(v => v.Id, v => new BlogId(v));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work with strongly typed Id objects. In this situation we get an exception:

> The relationship from 'Post' to 'Blog.Posts' with foreign key properties {'BlogId' : BlogId} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.

I've tried to solve it with implicit operators, IComparable interface, owned types, but none of these solutions work here. It simply ignores conversions of the BlogId type as part of the relationship creation process (`builder.Property(p => p.BlogId).HasConversion(v => v.Id, v => new BlogId(v));`).

Do you know any workaround or standard solution for such case? I would like to not make changes in the domain due to limitations in the persistence layer.

Comment: Why would Post have a property of type BlogId instead of just Blog?  EF will let you omit the foreign key property and just have an "Intependent Association" between the entities.  Behind the scenes EF will use a "Shadow Property" to track the BlogId.

Comment: @Pawel Maga, You requirement is pretty weird! You are wanting `one to many` relationship between `Blog` and `Post` but you also wanting `BlogId` to be primary key of the `Post`. How is it possible? If you make `BlogId` the primary key of the` Post` then would be `one to zero-or-one` relationship.

Comment: Hi @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks for your reply. Of course we can do what you said, remove this id and replace it with either integer Id or reference navigation property, but... the plan is to resign from separated persistence model and use only domain entities here. For this reason it will be the best to have all EF-related changes in the EF configuration. Therefore the desired solution is one that does not touch the domain, but if you cannot do it, then we have this final option. 
TanvirArjel there was one missing line in the example, Post has his own unique Id :) Sorry for that :)

Comment: But my question was why do you consider "BlogID" a domain object?  In any case EF mapping is pretty simplistic.  If you really want a free hand with the domain design, you'll probably want to leave the EF Entities looking like the storage model, and copy them into separate domain objects.

Comment: *"the plan is to resign from separated persistence model and use only domain entities here"* Sounds like bad plan to me. If you want to strictly follow DDD rules and not have *"persistence layer limitations*" (which I would call persistence model *requirements*), then separate models is the way to go - you can't force EF Core to follow DDD rules, there always will be limitations/not working things.

Comment: This is a philosophical question, whether it is worth combining the domain model with the persistence model. It has its pros and cons, and I think that we had enough discussions on Stack Overflow about this dilemma :) Here we talk about its disadvantages, we need to modify the domain object to meet the persistence model requirements. And in this question I care about minimizing the negative impact of this design.. the world is not perfect. If I can create mapping so that it does not affect the model - great, but if not then I will use the above-mentioned standard approach

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: @LinusCaldwell unfortunately not. It was fresh project, so it was easy to introduce a storage model as a solution for this kind of problems